# Importing 1.9m record csv file into MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import a rather large csv file into Workbench. It has 1.9m records in it. What is the best way to go about this?

I have tried:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE clients;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/MyComputer/Client.csv' 
INTO TABLE clients
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|,|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

This has however timed out after running for 22hours.

This is the timeout message I got.

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: Are there indexes on clients

Comment: Yes there are..

Comment: it this really taking 20 hours ?? , we had  30 lakh records. we used same load local syntax. ours completed with in minutes. are you connecting to remote mysql server or local server ??

Comment: Do you have (after those 22 hours) rows in your table, and how many? If not, make sure your line format (terminated by) is correct, e.g. by importing a csv of 10 lines. 2m rows should be a matter of minutes, not days. You may have significant load, connection problems, triggers, something locking or similiar sideeffects which might slow this down and which you may need to check.